# div shows on hover but not on mobile using active

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-selectors

So I have some divs that display more info on hover. I want to extend this to mobile. But since phone screens don't have a hover action I want to adapt this for mobile. I have tried using :active but that does not do anything

ps:

**I prefer using css for this but if there is no way to do so then JQuery solutions are acceptable.**

```
<div class="app">
   <i class="fa fa-adjust fa-3x"></i>
   <div class="app-text">App 1</div>
   <div>
      <ul class="hover-list">
         <li>first</li>
         <li>second</li>
         <li>third</li>
      </ul> 
   </div>
</div>

<div class="app">
   <i class="fa fa-anchor fa-3x"></i>
   <div class="app-text">App 2</div>
   <div>
      <ul class="hover-list">
         <li>first</li>
         <li>second</li>
         <li>third</li>
      </ul> 
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the style:

```
.app:hover, .app:active { 
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #8a898a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.app:hover > i { color: white; }

.app:hover ul, .app:active ul { 
    display: block;
}
```

UPDATE

per suggestions here is what I now have:

```
.app:hover, .app:active, .app:focus { 
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #8a898a;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.app:hover > i,
.app:active > i, 
.app:focus > i { color: white; }

.app:hover ul, .app:active ul, .app:focus ul { 
    display: block;
}
```

This works in the FireFox dev tools but not in my actual phone browser. Is it possible the necessary rules are getting overwritten? Any ideas on how to debug?

Comment: I created a fiddle using your code and works fine on iPhone/Safari and Android/Chrome. Can you give more details about the environment you're experiencing the issues in?

Comment: hmm... I am using iPhone/Safari and touching the icons does absolutely nothing. I don't know what could be different. What other details would you need?

Comment: There is focus Pseudo-class try using that.

Comment: tried this. Updated original posting with results

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use checked box?

Is this your desired effect?
https://jsfiddle.net/qunawes3/

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="appone">
<label for="appone">
  <div class="app">
    <i class="fa fa-adjust fa-3x"></i>
    <div class="app-text">App 1</div>
    <div>
      <ul class="hover-list">
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="apptwo">
<label for="apptwo">
  <div class="app">
    <i class="fa fa-anchor fa-3x"></i>
    <div class="app-text">App 2</div>
    <div>
      <ul class="hover-list">
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.app:hover,
#appone:checked + label > .app,
#apptwo:checked + label > .app{
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #8a898a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.app:hover > i {
  color: white;
}

.app:hover ul,
#appone:checked + label > .app,
#apptwo:checked + label > .app{
  display: block;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```